# React Native: keeping the icons position fixed

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-stylesheet

I am using `react-native-autocomplete-input` component's `<AutoComplete>`
I inserted two icons at left(search) and right(close) of `AutoComplete`.

```
       <View style={styles.searchSection}>
          <AntDesign
            name="search1"
            size={18}
            color="gray"
            style={styles.searchIcon}
          />
          <Autocomplete
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
            inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
            //data to show in suggestion
            data={filteredFilms}
            //default value if you want to set something in input
            defaultValue={
              JSON.stringify(selectedValue) === '{}'
                ? ''
                : selectedValue.title + selectedValue.id
            }
            // onchange of the text changing the state of the query
            // which will trigger the findFilm method
            // to show the suggestions
            onChangeText={(text) => findFilm(text)}
            placeholder="Search doctors, specialities, symptoms"
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              //you can change the view you want to show in suggestions
              <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    setSelectedValue(item);
                    setFilteredFilms([]);
                  }}>
                  <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.title + item.id}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )}
          />
          <AntDesign
            name="close"
            size={18}
            color="gray"
            style={styles.clearIcon}
          />
        </View>
```

Without typing keys, UI looks fine as below:

[image]

But when I start to type, both search and close icons are pushed down to center of suggestion:

[image]

Any suggestion, how I can keep both icons fixed at it's top position.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try attribute `alignItems:'flex-start'` in `styles.searchSection`.

For further alignment of icons, use `padingTop: 10` in both `searchIcon` and `clearIcon`.

Comment: Thank you @Laxminarayan for the guidance. 
I edited the answer with more precise information.